# Can I make Excel highlight a cell dependent on sum of 2 other cells?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a list of prices in a spreadsheet(numbers input manually). There are 2 seperate cells that show a) length of contract in years (1-5) and b) number of services required annually (2-12)

What I want to do is to get excel to highlight the correct price in the list accordingly. eg. if contract is 2 years and number of services is 4, i want it to higlight the cell showing £350.

Is this possible?

Comment: Highlight as in change the colour of the cell, or highlight as in make that cell the one which is selected?

Comment: HI, As in change the colour of the cell

Answer (score 0):

Conditional Formatting should work.  Under "Rule Type" you'd select 'use a formula to determine which cells to format.  Your formula is then entered as "=if(and(A1=2, B1=3)" as the condition which must be met to apply the format.

Be sure you pay attention to absolute vs relative cell references

Answer (score -1):

You can use Conditional Formatting to format cells depending on any rules (including highlighting/changing background colours etc) that you set.  Have a look on Youtube for some vids, alternatively [here's a quick link](http://www.contextures.com/xlCondFormat01.html)

Comment: Don't think that will work as the cell to be highlighted is dependent on what is shown in the other 2 cells. eg. if cell a = 2 and cell b=3, i need cell c to show £350 and be highlighted.....

Comment: Any chance of a sample workbook we can look at?

Comment: yes i will post one now....

Comment: how do you upload to here?